Cordova 12 app crashes after hours of geolocation tracking
I have a Cordova 12 application available on both iOS and Android, using various plugins including cordova-background-geolocation-plugin. My application can use geolocation for several hours continuously (both in the foreground and background) while storing the data. However, I am encountering an issue where the application crashes after running for a certain period of time.
I am using Crashlytics for crash reporting, but the information I retrieve isn't very helpful. I have noticed some errors in the Google console and have started addressing them, but other errors that are reported do not provide much insight.
Details:

Platform: iOS and Android
Cordova Version: 12
Framework: Angular with Cordova
Plugins Used:

cordova-plugin-geolocation v5.0.0
cordova-plugin-firebase-crash v8.0.0
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics v8.0.0
cordova-background-geolocation-plugin v2.0.10


Geolocation Settings:

Permissions: "always"
Automatic startup: Enabled
Battery optimization: Disabled



Configuration:
options = Object.assign({
    locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
    desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
    stationaryRadius: 10,
    distanceFilter: 10,
    interval: 10000,
    stopOnTerminate: true,
    notificationIconSmall: '@mipmap/notification_icon',
    notificationTitle: this.translateService.instant('playMode.title'),
    notificationText: this.translateService.instant('misc.active'),
    startForeground: true,
    pauseLocationUpdates: false,
    url: null,
    httpHeaders: {},
    maxLocations: 10,
    postTemplate: null
}, options);

Android vitals:

Android Vitals 1

Android Vitals 2

Android Vitals 3


Reproduction Steps:
This issue is not easy to reproduce consistently. It happens after the application has been running for several hours, making it difficult to pinpoint the exact cause.
I am looking for ideas on what might be causing these crashes and if there is a better monitoring solution that can help me pinpoint and resolve these errors.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
